# Are disconnected PV panels damaged when exposed to sunlight?

Tags: solar-cell, output, switching

Can PV solar panels be exposed to sun without being connected to controller and batteries?  Have fixed panels on RV, and would like ability to switch (at controller input) to moveable panels on ground when parked shady area. Hoping to avoid having to cover fixed panels on very tall trailer.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question and I cannot for certain tell you the answer except to say that I leave solar panels out in the sun regularly not connected to anything and they have not developed any damage.  I would be more worried about the connectors of your panels when not in use accidentally coming in contact with something connecting a circuit and causing damage or a fire.

I look at PV panels like a battery with a + and a - that when not connected to anything has a potential, but not utilized until the connected or a circuit is formed.

I would be more concerned about the "shady areas" and your fixed panels and the potential for hot spotting and damage from that.  Your panels should have bypass diodes, but if they are old, or if they don't have enough, your panels could be damaged (or worse, a fire) if they are partially shaded.  look up bypass diodes and hot spotting on goolge.

I am fairly certain that again, this phenomenon will only happen if the panels are actually in use and connected to a circuit.  So if the fixed panels are disconnected in the shady areas you should be just fine.  Happy camping.

Comment: +1 for mentioning bypass diodes, I had not read about that until today. And I believe you are correct, in that it is the current that has the potential for damage. If the solar panel is not connected to anything, then it should have no current flow. Though, the charge potential may still occur even if they are not hooked up, thus a connector cover to prevent injury may be prudent.